# ( Error) The instance member widget can't be accessed in an initializer.Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

In Flutter i am passing data to a new screen, Here is my first_Screen sending data

```
                        Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => updatenote(
                              id:      snapshot.data[index],
                              title:   snapshot.data[index]['title'],
                              content: snapshot.data[index]['content']),
                          ),
                        );
```

Here is my second screen getting data,

```
class updatenote extends StatefulWidget {
const updatenote({super.key, required this.id , required this.title , required this.content });
final dynamic id;
final dynamic title;
final dynamic content;

@override
State<updatenote> createState() => _updatenoteState();
}

class _updatenoteState extends State<updatenote> {

// instance of text_ediitng controllers 
final titleController   = TextEditingController(text: widget.title);
final contentController = TextEditingController(text: widget.content);
```

now the problem is i can't access widget.title and widget.content outside of my build , here i want to pass that data as a parameter to the TextEditingController. but get this (error)..

> *The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different
> expression*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define them as `late`

```
late final titleController = TextEditingController(text: widget.title);
late final contentController = TextEditingController(text: widget.content);
```

This makes it that the assignment happens lazily, meaning it happens at the point where you first use them. This allows it to use `widget` there

Comment: thank you so much ! it was an easy fix for a total newbie like me lol .

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this:

```
late final titleController;
late final contentController;
      @override
      void initState() {
        // instance of text_ediitng controllers 
        final titleController = TextEditingController(text: widget.title);
        final contentController = TextEditingController(text: 
        widget.content);
        super.initState();
      }
```

Comment: i never tried your solution but still thank you for your response ! it does not mean your code was wrong , i just tried the much shorter version below and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class updatenote extends StatefulWidget {
  final titleController   = TextEditingController();
  final contentController = TextEditingController();
  final dynamic id;
  final dynamic title;
  final dynamic content;
  const updatenote({super.key, required this.id , required this.title , required this.content }) {
    titleController.text = title;
    contentController.text = content;
  }

  @override
  State<updatenote> createState() => _updatenoteState();
}
```

Comment: bro first i tried Ivo's answer and it worked !!! , between thank for your previous response, i was happy to see a fellow Pakistani here ! may you achieve high Ameen .